# Cron Jobs in Cognos- Changing owner

Tags: cron, cognos

Right now in Cognos, We are getting scheduled reports from a guy X. But since X has left the organization. I want to replace X , from my mail-id, such that everybody gets the scheduled reports from my mail-id. I have already done following with no results:
1. Changed the email  credentials for cron jobs in Data Manager.
2. Changed the credentials , under modify schedule
3. Changed the owner of the report.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 is the only thing you need to do for reports.

Here's the detailed instruction:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cc.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cc_id9882change_schedule_credentials.html